# Issues with Cyrillic character set in PHP (Black Diamonds & question marks)

Tags: php, character-encoding, ftp

I am having issues with retrieving and processing data that is in Russian using the cyrillic character set.

I get the data in a text file from an FTP server with the code below and it displays every character with the black diamonds with question marks inside.

If I view it directly by accessing the FTP address with the browser, it displays correctly.

I have tried changing this line:

to

and

and while I get different results, none show the same as when accessing the file directly by the browser.

I'm not sure how to get the code to display the same as the browser when I view it directly

This would be an example of how I view the text file directly which displays correctly : ftp://username:password@ftp.mysite.com/test.txt

This is the code I am using which displays the black diamonds with question marks (other other incorrect characters, depending on the charset mentioned above).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<?php
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$server = "ftp://ftp.mysite.com"
$remoteFile = "test.txt";
$conn = ftp_connect($server);
if (@ftp_login($conn, $username, $password)) {
    echo "";
    } 
else {
    echo "";
    }
ob_start();
ftp_get($conn, 'php://output', $remoteFile, FTP_ASCII);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
ftp_close($conn); 
echo $data;
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Try utf8_encode on $data

Comment: Thank you, while this does indeed stop the 'black diamond/question mark' issue, it still does not display correctly. I'm again disappointed at the downvote (with no explanation why) as I only post here when I have been unable to resolve it myself.

Comment: oh I noticed, you are using transfer mode for ftp to ASCII, try switching to Binary mode with FTP_BINARY flag in place of FTP_ASCII flag

Comment: Hello @vishwakarma09 Thank you for your help. This unfortunately doesn't seem to help, the characters are still not displayed in the correct format. I have done an mb_detect_encoding($data); on it and it claims it is UTF-8 but I can't see how that can be? I'm completely stumped with this :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by using `mb_convert_encoding` by adding the following line :

```
$new_data = mb_convert_encoding($data, "utf-8", "Windows-1251");
```

with the resulting code as :

```
<html>
<?php
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$server = "ftp://ftp.mysite.com"
$remoteFile = "test.txt";
$conn = ftp_connect($server);
if (@ftp_login($conn, $username, $password)) {
    echo "";
    } 
else {
    echo "";
    }
ob_start();
ftp_get($conn, 'php://output', $remoteFile, FTP_ASCII);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
ftp_close($conn); 
$new_data = mb_convert_encoding($data, "utf-8", "Windows-1251");
echo $data;
?>
</html>
```

Hope this helps someone...